# MySQL one to many relationship, with shared values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL DB with 3 tables.

profile,
p_tags,
tags

DB:

```
profile
pid | name

ptags
ptid | pid | tagid

tags
tagid | tag
```

The DB looks something like this

```
profile
pid | name
 1    Randy
 2    Jeff
 3    Mike

ptags
ptid | pid | tagid
 1      1      1
 2      1      2 
 3      2      1
 4      2      3 
 5      3      1
 6      3      2
 7      3      3 

tags
tagid | tag
  1     science
  2     filosophy
  3     hydrology
```

What I need is to create a query that displays The names in the profile that have shared tags and the total shared tags

I.E.

```
Results
Name  | Name2 | Count
Randy - Jeff - 1
Randy - Mike - 2
Jeff - Randy - 1
Jeff - Mike - 2 
Mike - Randy - 2
Mike - Jeff - 2
```

And so on.

I dunno if I explained it correctly.

I read

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

From a link from another post similar to this one, but just can't get my head around it :).

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42bde6

Comment: I would recommend for anything that involves MySQL to setup something like a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some dummy data so we don't have to do it ourselves. You're more likely to get an answer if you include a link in addition to what you've already set up.

Comment: recommend for you site phptherightway... [PDO Extension](http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension), [MySQL Extension](http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension)

Comment: Thank you Both for your suggestions I will implement them in future questions.  In fact I just did one (I think) for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in query use join:

```
SELECT p1.name Name1, p2.name Name2, Count(tagid)
FROM ptags AS t1
INNER JOIN ptags AS t2 ON t2.tagid = t1.tagid and t2.ptid <> t1.ptid 
INNER JOIN profile AS p1 ON p1.pid = t1.pid 
INNER JOIN profile AS p2 ON p2.pid = t2.pid 
GROUP BY p1.name, p2.name
```

and if you need only one row for pair of firstname  then try this:

```
SELECT p1.firstname Name1, p2.firstname Name2, Count(t1.tagid)
FROM profile_hashtags AS t1
INNER JOIN profile_hashtags AS t2 
  ON t2.tagid = t1.tagid and t2.pHid > t1.pHid 
INNER JOIN `profile` AS p1 ON p1.pid = t1.pid 
INNER JOIN `profile` AS p2 ON p2.pid = t2.pid 
GROUP BY p1.firstname, p2.firstname;
```

Comment: Thanks for this Adam. The problem I'm having with this query is that it's returning only the first 2.  As per the suggestions above I added an sqlfiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e618

Comment: The modified code so it works with the fiddle db is: SELECT p1.firstname Name1, p2.firstname Name2, Count(t1.tagid)
         FROM profile_hashtags AS t1
         INNER JOIN profile_hashtags AS t2 ON t2.tagid = t1.tagid and t2.pHid <> t1.pHid 
         INNER JOIN profile AS p1 ON p1.pid = t1.pHid 
         INNER JOIN profile AS p2 ON p2.pid = t2.pHid
         GROUP BY p1.firstname, p2.firstname

Comment: ok, but you only change names of tables and fields... Do you expect different result?

Comment: No Adam, I was just following the suggestions, I didn't expect different results and as I write this I'm reading up on other options. http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/.  Like I posted before I'm a complete beginner on MySQL relationships.  I just posted an update and I'm trying to figure it out on my own.  I read the query you did and it took me a few minutes just to understand your approach to get those results :).  I'll keep on reading.  Thanks again

Comment: Thank you Adam, I really appreciate all the help and comments regarding this problem.  I realized that I have a lot of reading to do in regards to Joins and MySQL in general :).

Comment: This can be helpful: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php , I recommend techonthenet.com as simple and fast help